# SQLite3: advantages/disadvantages of indexing an Integer column of NON-unique data

Tags: indexing, sqlite

Is it advantageous or disadvantageous to create an index on a column whose data type is of integer (integer because later it will be used by comparison operators) when the rows are NOT unique? For example, suppose we have 500,000 rows that consists of numbers between 0 to 100 (percent);

**Q2**: In case the indexing will not result in gaining more performance, how can we increase the performance of query in such scenarios?

**Q3**: In case the indexing would be advantageous, since the data of column will be later used by comparison operators (bigger than, lesser than), is it advisable to use **Binary collate**?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html).

Comment: @CL. read the documentation but still can't find the answer to my questions